# How to set an element position using measurments in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I wanted to know how to set an element position depending on measures, for example if my document is 1000 pixels wide and 500 pixels in height, How to set an element to be 100 pixels away from the left and 100 from the top ?
can this be done ?
and thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Add a new guide at the appropriate position (View > New Guide), then ensure that Snap to Guides is on.  When your cursor is near the guide(s) it'll be pulled next to the guide.